How to use Blensor output simulated depth map
I have used blensor to simulate depth map and output it as a .pcd file. However, I couldn't find a way to open it. Does anyone have solutions?
I tried to use z pass to generate depth image and then used it recover a point cloud. However, the generated point cloud is always like a corner.

What is Blensor?

It is called blender sensor simulator. I used it to simulate LiDAR and it works well, BUT if I use depth map or depth camera. I can't read output files.
